# mysql join return 0 for one column with other columns intact

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I wish to join multiple tables like- `Categories`, `menus`, `restaurants`, `reviews`, etc.
to return the restaurants that provide the inserted food with their prices.
Everything works except `numberOfReviews` in `reviews` table.

If a restaurant has no reviews then output should be `0` for `numOfReviews` column but other column values should be retrieved i.e. price, name, etc.

With following query I get all fields as `null` and `count(numReviews)` as `0`:

```
 select r.id
     ,r.`Name`
     ,r.`Address`
     ,r.city
     ,r.`Rating`
     ,r.`Latitude`
     ,a.`AreaName`
     ,m.`Price`
     ,count(rv.id)
 from `categories` c, `menus` m, `restaurants` r, areas a, reviews rv
 where m.`ItemName`="tiramisu"
     and c.`restaurant_id`=r.`id`
     and m.`category_id`=c.id
     and r.`AreaId`=a.`AreaId`
```

and if I can't match `rv.restaurant_id=r.id` in `where` clause(obviously).

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

**edited**

```
    select  r.id, 
 r.`Name`,
 r.`Address`,
 r.city,
 r.`Rating`,
 r.`Latitude`,
 a.`AreaName`, 
 m.`Price`, 
 r.`Longitude`, 
 r.Veg_NonVeg,
 count(rv.id)
 from restaurants r LEFT JOIN `reviews` rv on rv.`restaurant_id`=r.`id`
inner join `categories` c on c.`restaurant_id` = r.id
inner join `menus` m on m.`category_id` = c.id
inner join `areas` a on a.`AreaId` = r.`AreaId`
 where m.`ItemName`="tiramisu"
```

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` if you want to return anything when there are no matches in the `reviews` table.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks i tried this but now am getting just a single row when I write count(rv.id). See my edited question

Comment: `count(numReviews)` is same as `count(rv.id)` ?

Comment: are you looking for [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: @z22 If you want multiple rows when you use an aggregate function like `COUNT()`, you need to use `GROUP BY` to get separate counts for each ID. Otherwise it combines everything into one big count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use this old school syntax for the jointures.

Here is a query that may solve your problem:

```
SELECT R.id
    ,R.Name
    ,R.Address
    ,R.city
    ,R.Rating
    ,R.Latitude
    ,R.Longitude
    ,A.AreaName
    ,M.Price
    ,R.Veg_NonVeg
    ,COUNT(RV.id) AS numOfReviews
FROM restaurants R
INNER JOIN categories C ON C.restaurant_id = R.id
INNER JOIN menus M ON M.category_id = C.id
INNER JOIN areas A ON A.AreaId = R.AreaId
LEFT JOIN reviews RV ON RV.restaurant_id = R.id
WHERE M.ItemName = 'tiramisu'
GROUP BY R.id, R.Name, R.Address, R.city, R.Rating, R.Latitude, R.Longitude, A.AreaName, M.Price, R.Veg_NonVeg
```

I used explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax instead of your old school syntax and I modified the jointure with table `reviews` in order to get the expected result. The `GROUP BY` clause is required to use the aggregate function `COUNT`, every rows will be grouped by the enumerated columns (every column except the one used by the function).

Here is another solution that simplify the `GROUP BY` clause and allow the modification of `SELECT` statement without having to worry about the fact that every columns need to be part of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT R.id
    ,R.Name
    ,R.Address
    ,R.city
    ,R.Rating
    ,R.Latitude
    ,R.Longitude
    ,A.AreaName
    ,M.Price
    ,R.Veg_NonVeg
    ,NR.numOfReviews
FROM restaurants R
INNER JOIN (SELECT R2.id
                ,COUNT(RV.id) AS numOfReviews
            FROM restaurants R2
            LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews RV ON RV.restaurant_id = R2.id
            GROUP BY R2.id) NR ON NR.id = R.id
INNER JOIN categories C ON C.restaurant_id = R.id
INNER JOIN menus M ON M.category_id = C.id
INNER JOIN areas A ON A.AreaId = R.AreaId
WHERE M.ItemName = 'tiramisu'
```

As you can see here I added a new jointure on a simple subquery that does the aggregation job in order to provide me the expected number of reviews for each restaurant.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with joining tables without join statement when possible. Argumentation?

Comment: @Juru There is no difference between both syntax in term of performance but the explicit notation is a best practice. By using this notation you separate the conditions that are specific to the jointures (`ON T1.column1 = T2.column2`) and this unique argument may change everything when you're dealing with multiple tables and complex conditions. Another argument is that you have the same syntax no matter the type of jointures you define (`INNER, LEFT, RIGHT,..`).

Comment: @JoëlSalamin- thanks i tried this but now am getting just a single row when I write `count(rv.id)`. See my edited question

Comment: @z22 My bad, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause in order to have the expected `numOfReviews`. Try this new query and tell me if it helps.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin- thanks mate, it works :) I didn't get the use of group by on so many parameters. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @z22 I edited my post to add explanation on the `GROUP BY` clause and I also added a second solution that may helps you to simplify the readability of your query by avoiding this huge `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I never heard of that best practice before... The way that programmers write their queries now is totally unstructured anyway. I always write indented readable queries with clear separation of what is join related.  For the same syntax for all joins. 99% of the queries I have wrote and seen are without special joins, so why bother on an exception. The important thing is that it works but for me using the join clauses is not better.

Comment: @Juru It's a matter of preferences, I'm not telling you that you're doing wrong because your result will be exactly as performant as the way I'm suggesting. But if you want more info about these best practices, have a look at http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2011/10/03/a-list-of-sql-best-practices.aspx

Comment: @Juru You can refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122.aspx and http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-1 to see which sql syntax is currently being used. The old syntax isn't deprecated but I guess it's always a better practice to move with the change :)